# Override paste: to format text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, paste, nspasteboard

I would like to capture a string being pasted into a control and apply some custom formatting  to the string before being pasted.

How is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `paste:` in your view/control (paste: is part of the `UIResponderStandardEditActions` informal protocol). At the simplest, you'd do this:

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender
{
   UIPasteboard* pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
   NSString* rawString = pasteboard.string;
   NSString* formattedString =  // do something fun with rawString here
   pasteboard.string = formattedString;
   [super paste:sender];
}
```

This is assuming you don't need to do something terribly fancy with the string (like inserting animated smileys or something), in which case you shouldn't call `super` but do the insertion yourself (if you are doing this on a `UITextView` you can use the `selectedRange` property to do the insertion properly).

EDIT: To get data from a `NSPasteBoard` you should use `–stringForType:` or one of [several other data access methods](http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000328-DontLinkElementID_1). You might have to validate the string/data to make sure it's something that can be pasted.

You probably shouldn't call `super` but use

```
[self insertText:formattedString];
```

if you're doing this on a NSTextView. If you're working with another class you have to find out what's appropriate in that context.

Comment: I guess I tagged this post with iPhone, but I'm looking more for implementation for NSPasteBoard, specifically the [super paste:sender] part.